# xubuntu 16.04 - placing a window on defined location

Tags: x11, xfce, window-manager, xfwm4

I use three monitors. When a window with a specific title is opened it should be placed on defined location (monitor). It looks like xfwm4 window manager doesn't provide such functionality. Compiz has a plugin place but I'm looking for a lightweight window manager without compositing. Do you know some wm which provide such functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

icewm (my favourite) can do it: http://www.icewm.org/FAQ/IceWM-FAQ-6.html

and there is an universal solution called: [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/), which can be used with almost all window managers.